# How to update the environment value in Flutter Pubspeck.yaml

Tags: flutter, dart, environment

I want to update the environment value in a flutter project.
how should I do it?.

Is there any way we can do this using commands?

Comment: What do you mention as environment values? If you are asking about setting up development and production codes please have a look into flavours in flutter

Comment: Mhm pubspeck 

Comment: for updating the dependencies in pubspeck, we use flutter pub upgrade --major-versions. I wanted to know if there is some kind of command for upgrading the environment  declared in pubspeck.yaml with single line command. I had updated the  environment manually in pubspeck file but is there any command for it